icecat cron is always running, but no products updated?
I am using https://github.com/IcecatNV/magento-extension to import data from icecat into my Magento 2.4.6 store.
The extension is connected to icecat, I made the mapping and when I import data on product level (button in product) it works. But it seems, the cron is not doing what it is supposed to. I set up a cron job to run every minute: php bin/magento icecat:queue-runner
Running this in the CLI, it just runs, no errors no nothing. When I click the "Full Import" button in the icecat config area, its just saying "There is already Queue in progress" ... sounds right, but nothing is changing on product level.
Import Statistics from the extension do not update ... last run according to the stats was in May.
The Any ideas what might be wrong?
